# Home folder in Webapplication

Tags: php, html

Can somebody explain me what does this link mean?

```
<?php header("Location:user/#/home")?>
```

This line is inside index.php file, that exists at the same level as user folder and user folder has another folder called home inside. My query is what does this # sign mean and what is the purpose?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP, the [header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) method is how you send HTTP headers back to the user's browser.  The Location header instructs the browser that the requested item has moved to a new location and thus the browser should redirect the user to the new location.  In short, this is an HTTP redirect.

From the PHP side, your server will first see a request to the file above, and then a second request for the path "user/". Depending on how your web server is configured, this could go to the same PHP file, or to a different PHP file for processing.

Specifically the hash sign ("#").  This is a [fragment identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier) within a URL and is traditionally used to scroll a user to a specific portion of a page. So taking the example "user/#/home", this user would be redirected to page "user/", and then the browser would try to scroll to the anchor "/home" on the resulting page.